# C# Change between specific data classes in DTO

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

We are getting data for our application.

We have common set of data with common fields, PurchaseDate, Manufacturer, PurchaseAmount,
Then we have specific subclass (which contains specific vehicle info, Aircraft wingspan, or car miles/per gallon, or Boat floatation metrics.

Instead of having classes which are not required, how can we create a model with a specific data type?

```
public class VehicleInfo
{
    public Datetime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int PurchaseAmount { get; set; }

    // specific data, not all these needed
    public AircraftInfo AircraftInfo {get;set;} 
    public CarInfo Carinfo {get;set;} 
    public BoatInfo BoatInfo {get;set;}
 }
```

I read Dependency injection is not ideal practice for DTOs? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/83166/354368

Comment: Also you loose all inheritance - which may bite you very badly if your DTO use case supports inheritance. If it does not - it already did bite you.

Comment: Inheritance solves this. What has DI got to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

You can choose from "is-a" (inheritance) or "has-a" (composition).

You already have what is common to all vehicles

```
public class VehicleInfo
{
    public Datetime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int PurchaseAmount { get; set; }
}
```

So you can use inheritance (and make VehicleInfo abstract)

```
public class AircraftInfo : VehicleInfo
{
    ...
}
```

or use composition

```
public class AircraftInfo
{
   public VehicleInfo VehicleInfo { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

or mix composition and inheritance

```
public class PassengerAircraftInfo : AircraftInfo
{
    public PassengerVehicleInfo PassengerVehicleInfo { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

If you have e.g. 5 out of 10 vehicles that shares a set of common properties in addition to common properties you already have, inheritance will require another abstract class that inherits from VehicleInfo. Composition will require a new property on each of the 5 vehicles.

What is best, depends on final result of your analysis for the project.  Number of inheritance levels should be kept to a minimum in order to keep code complexity low.